# Why is SSH from inside docker container to other instance/server so slow

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, docker

I have a docker container which acts as an installer.
The container contains the necessary tools to run an ansible script. 
This ansible script creates some EC2-instances.
But there need to be some additional configuration on each seperate server. So I try to SSH to a created EC2 instance but it seems to be very slow from inside my container. Does someone knows why or what could be a good solution?

Comment: A good first port of call is to run the playbook with the verbose flag if you haven't done so already (`ansible-playbook -vvv` or if using vagrant add `ansible.verbose = "vvv"` where you kick off the provisioning in ansible).